# PyQt5 Application Window Not Showing

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to code an application that will allow the user to view a list of Tag IDs, as well as its description, and allow the user to check off each Tag ID that they would like to import data from. At this point I am working on developing the UI only.

The code below worked and would show the application window until I added the *itemChanged* function & connection. Now, when I run this code, only the print statement from the new function will show. The window never shows and the entire application promptly exits (see image for outcome of running script).

Additionally, you'll notice that we get the checkState of each type of item - I only want the checkState of the Tag ID.

[image: output]

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLineEdit, QTableView, QHeaderView, QVBoxLayout, QAbstractItemView
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QSortFilterProxyModel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem

class myApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.resize(1000, 500)
        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        
        tagIDs = ('Tag_1', 'Tag_2', 'Tag_3', 'Tag_4', 'Tag_5')
        descriptions = ('Description_1', 'Description_2', 'Description_3', 'Description_4', 'Description_5')


        model = QStandardItemModel(len(tagIDs), 2)
        model.itemChanged.connect(self.itemChanged)
        model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Tag IDs', 'Description'])

        for i in range(len(tagIDs)):
            
            item1 = QStandardItem(tagIDs[i])
            item1.setCheckable(True)
            
            item2 = QStandardItem(descriptions[i])
            
            model.setItem(i, 0, item1)
            model.setItem(i, 1, item2)

        filterProxyModel = QSortFilterProxyModel()
        filterProxyModel.setSourceModel(model)
        filterProxyModel.setFilterCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        filterProxyModel.setFilterKeyColumn(1)
        

        searchField = QLineEdit()
        searchField.setStyleSheet('font-size: 20px; height: 30px')
        searchField.textChanged.connect(filterProxyModel.setFilterRegExp)
    
        mainLayout.addWidget(searchField)

        table = QTableView()
        table.setStyleSheet('font-size: 20px;')
        table.verticalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
        table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(1, QHeaderView.Stretch)

        table.setModel(filterProxyModel)
        table.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        
        mainLayout.addWidget(table)



        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

    def itemChanged(self, item):
        print("Item {!r} checkState: {}".format(item.text(), item.checkState()))


def main():
    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myAppControl = myApp()
    myAppControl.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: "I only want the checkState of the Tag ID.": that is because you're connecting the signal *before* adding items to the model. Move the signal connection *after* filling the data, and eventually add a check for the item's `column()` in `itemChanged` to filter only the column you need. In any case, that question has nothing to do with your main problem: remember that each post should always have *one* question. If you need more details about that other aspect, you have to create a new question.

Comment: Thank you, I'll separate the questions next time.
This also worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Header settings that depend on the model **must** always be set when a model is set.

Move `table.setModel(filterProxyModel)` right after the creation of the table or, at least, before `table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode` (the vertical `setSectionResizeMode()` is generic for the whole header and doesn't cause problems).

Comment: Thanks musicamante. I assumed the table is created after `table = QTableView()`, am I wrong here? I tried moving `table.setModel(filterProxyModel)` to after `mainLayout.addWidget(table)` with no success. Its odd to me that this all worked before I added the `itemChanged` function.

Comment: @Jad please read more carefully what I wrote: you must call `setModel()` **before** `setSectionResizeMode()`. This has nothing to do with the fact that the table is added to a layout or that you connected the `itemChanged` signal, the problem is that you're trying to set a section resize mode **before** the table view has a model set: there is no such column so Qt hangs and eventually crashes because you're trying to set a property for a specific column that doesn't exist.

Comment: @Jad You're very welcome. Remember that if an answer solves your problem, you should mark it as accepted by clicking the gray tick mark on its left.